# Rewrite rule to redirect to a particular filename.php

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules, callbacks

I'm using the Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) I want to write a rule that will be take a URL (that is specified in the user's accnt on a video encoding service as a callback URL) and then run the .php at the end of the callback URL.

In short, the video encoding service will send a callback once a file has been encoded. I need to catch that notification and then act on it.

btw, I also looked at WP Router (https://github.com/jbrinley/WP-Router) but it feels like overkill to me. I've used the Monkeyman plugin before with much success. I just can't seem to zero in on this particular add_rewrite_rule so I can process the callback request.

Comment: You need to post some of your code -- show us what you have so far.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy - I'd LOVE to, but that's kinda the point. I can't find a working example. There's one similar question in the WP.org forums with no answer and it's closed. Certainly WP can field/catch a callback to a particular (read: specified) URL/myfile/php, correct? The question I'm asking is...how? :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.